# carrierwave minimagick converted svg not compatible

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, svg, carrierwave, minimagick

I have a carrierwave installed with mini-magick on a rails-3-2 project.
I am facing a problems creating versions for uploaded svg images.
My uploader code is as follows

```
class SVGUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file

  process resize_to_fit: [400, 400]
  version :thumb do
    resize_to_fit(140, 140)
  end

  def extension_white_list
    [:svg]
  end

  def store_dir
    @dir ||= if ENV['PARALLEL_TEST_GROUPS']
      "system/uploads/#{ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER']}/#{Rails.env}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.name}"
    else
      "system/uploads/#{Rails.env}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id.to_s}"
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is when ever I upload any svg image, it takes a very long time to convert. and when I try to display the image browsers don't render them.

Anybody faced this issue? Please help.

Comment: SVG images seem to be browser dependent. Try following this [blog](http://jonathandean.com/2013/01/retina-screen-ready-using-vector-svg-images-and-still-supporting-crappy-browsers/). This might solve your problem.

Comment: seems like mini magick generates the svg as a standalone file. Which becomes incompatible within browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I saving without format svg to png

I solve this away:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base   
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes   
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process :set_content_type

  version :super_thumb, :if => :is_picture? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]   
  end

  protected

  def is_picture?(picture)
    return false if set_content_type(picture).include?('svg')
    set_content_type(picture).include?('image')   
  end 
end
```